# MySql Need query that checks one condition and than checks for a second condition before returning result

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table, Food_table with fields and rows:

```
food_type | food_name    | food_price
Meat      | steak        | 7.00 
Fruit     | red_apple    | 1.00
Fruit     | green_apple  | 1.10
Fruit     | yellow_apple | 0.50 
... etc
```

So how would I go about selecting say, All fruit that are apples and fall within price of a dollar + .10%, more or less ( $.90 >= food_price <= $1.10 ).

So this query would return red apple and green apple because they are fruits and are also apples AND their price is within $.90 and $1.10.

In the given example, I know the price, However, what if I did not know the price of the fruit?

My query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Food_table WHERE 
food_type = 'Fruit' AND food_name LIKE '%apple%'  "
```

However, I'm missing the price clause.

Thank you guys/gals

Further explanation:
If I have a 2 select box where a user selects the food_type, food_name and enters a price, how can I return that food with the price being 10% more or less?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot add a "price BETWEEN 0.90 AND 1.10"?

Comment: Check the PHP code I answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parametrize the percentage, you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Food_table
WHERE food_type = 'Fruit'
AND food_name LIKE '%apple%'
AND price BETWEEN 
    (0.90*(SELECT price FROM Food_table WHERE food_name = 'some_food')) 
    AND (1.10*(SELECT price FROM Food_table WHERE food_name = 'some_food'));
```

**EDIT:** For PHP:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT *
FROM Food_table
WHERE food_type = '" . $food_type . "'
AND food_name LIKE '" . $food_name . "'
AND price BETWEEN " . ($price*0,9) . " AND " . ($price*1,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Food_table
WHERE food_type = 'Fruit'
AND food_name LIKE '%apple%'
AND price BETWEEN 0.90 AND 1.10
```

I simply added the condition you asked about in the `WHERE` clause; I have no test set but it should work.

The last condition could also be written as

```
AND food_price >= 0.90 AND food_price <= 1.10
```

Choose the one you like more, I personally find the first version more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the example I gave above, I know the price, what if I did not know the price?

Comment: Sorry, could you please make an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it that way:

```
SELECT * FROM Food_table WHERE food_type = 'Fruit' AND food_name LIKE '%apple%' AND food_price >= 0.90 AND food_price <= 1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the price and the price is say X, and the decimal representation of the percentage range (i.e. 0.1) is Y, you can use simple math and do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Food_table
WHERE food_type = 'Fruit'
AND food_name LIKE '%apple%'
AND price BETWEEN X - (X * Y) AND X + (X * Y)
```